# ASP.NET Core MVC how to add theming support in dynamically what is the standard?

Tags: css, sass, asp.net-core-mvc, scss-mixins

I have an ASP.NET Core mvc web application, in which the UI relies heavily on scss.

One option to have a theme support by css variables but as I am using scss heavily there was a problems as darken and lighten cannot used with scss variable mixing. do not know some other potential problems,

Then I figure out other way as theme support using scss mixing pattern.

There I got a problem how it dynamically apply? as scss generated on server end and cannot see a way to change it dynamically as with above approach.

3rd I found a way to do it with separate theme files in theme wise and load it based on the user selection and saved it in DB .. I know it not the truly dynamic but can be a workaround.

Any standard way of doing theming with scss emphasis the point how it change the theme dynamically?

Comment: Hi @Prageeth godage, what is your scenario? Why do you want to dynamically apply the css?

Comment: @Rena, There is a requirement as each user can choose his preffered theme colors ...some drop down...based on that ... we need to change the appearance of our web site.